# windows virtual server 2013 ftp site processing time

Tags: c#, windows, ftp, server

I have 2 windows virtual servers they have the same memory and processor, and the same ftp site (code MVC C#) the code is the same. its running on IIS web server

The problem is in one server the code runs in 20 sec, on the second server it take 2 min 20 sec. wy is this happening?

What does code do? it search a folder for an image them makes a smaller copy of it, a thumbnail, and read a code bar usin zxing library.

Could it be folder permissions? Server permissions? i have no control over the server i just did the site. And since the code is exactly the same i don't understand.

Thanks

Comment: Is time you get response time or processing time?

Comment: the 20sec in server one and the 2min20sec in server two, Corresponds from the time that i press a button to the time the thumbnails are shown. so processing time.

Comment: it would be helpful to isolate things like network delay, DNS, windows updates. you can try using server IP address if you were using domain to rule out DNS. since you did the site, is there any log? otherwise it's hard give a definite answer.

Answer (score 1):

short answer the problem was indeed my code. the client had the code running on both servers for 2 months now and in server 2 the ftp folder had 25GB of tiff images. the search for the file was taking for ever.

thx for the help yantaq